# Visual Basic application store Settings in different paths

Tags: vb.net

need to ask, I have simple app, which had one textbox and one button. When I type something to that textbox and push that button, it saves to my Settings...

see:

```
Dim Settings As New My.MySettings
  Settings.something = TextBox2.Text
        Settings.Save()
MessageBox.Show(Settings.something.ToString)
```

Everything works great, but when I build it and run for example from my desktop path, Enter number save it and close it. When I make a copy of this file to my documents path and open it, nothing loaded, but when I start it from the place where I last save it, it loads properly.

In the short description:

If I run app on my Desktop path and make a save, when I close the app and copy this file (.exe) to another path, I need to load previous saved data from Desktop path, or other different location.

**Save in path A, copy it from and open anywhere in path B, C, D... etc.**

Is it possible, if yes, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like the 'SaveSetting" method

```
SaveSetting("MyApp", "Form1", "Text", "ValueToSave")
```

The first, second and third parameters indicate a "Path" where your value will be saved, and the fourth is the value itself.

Then, you can load the saved value using the following method:

```
MyText = GetSetting("MyApp", "Form1", "Text", "DefaultValue")
```

Note that the first three parameters must be the same as used on the save method, and the fourth is the default value, in case no previous data has been saved.